# Warning: substr_count(): Empty substring in C:\xampp\htdocs\tugasakhirhotel\coba\pesan\index.php on line 33

Tags: php

I make Hotel Booking and i want, if there is a room book 'echo full'

```
$stra = "1 2 4";          **/*rooms booked*/**
$strb = $ressi;           **/* all room from hotel (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)*/**
$arrayb = explode(",", $strb);

foreach($arrayb as $z){
    $countz = substr_count($stra,$z);
    if($countz==0){
        echo "empty".$z;
    }else if($countz==1){
        echo "full";
    }
}
```

if there no room number at $stra echo empty; else echo full;

Comment: Quick question: what if the hotel has more than 9 rooms? If `10` is booked, your code would incorrectly report room `1` as being booked!

Comment: We need to know what `$ressi` is

Comment: Why do you add a `<br>` to the substr_count? That will make your if() useless.

Comment: You explode $strb with comma and yet your string is space delimited? Really? Typo or is that really the case?

Comment: Andreas Sorry I'm not got at writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables are what I think they are then I believe a better option is to explode the booked rooms to an array too and use array_diff to find which is available.

```
$stra = "1 2 4";          **/*rooms booked*/**
$strb = $ressi;           **/* all room from hotel*/**
$arrayb = explode(",", $strb);
$arraya = explode(" ", $stra);

var_dump(array_diff($arrayb, $arraya));
// Output is available rooms
```

See output of code here: https://3v4l.org/Q3kkn